# Find all possible cuts of an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm working on an optimization problem and need to list all the possible cuts of an undirected graph. Specifically, i'm interested in finding all the edge subsets that disconnects the graph in two vertex subsets.

In detail:

In an undirected graph G(V,E) where V is the set of vertices and E the set of edges. a cut forms two vertex subsets A and B such that:

A **union** B= V

and

A **intersection** B= empty set

A and B establish C (subset of E) such that each edge in C connectes two vertices, one in A and one in B. i'm interested in finding all possible subsets C such that: for every C which is a graph cut of there's no cut  C' such that  C' is a subset of C.

your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How many vertices will your graph have? Are you sure that you want to find all cuts? It is an NP-hard problem (max cut could be solved with this algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know it is an NP-hard problem. However, i'm not interested in solving this problem for large number of vertices. The maximum number of vertices would not exceed 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that came to my mind. It may not be the most efficient one but it will return the correct result.

The idea is to grow a region starting from a vertex and find the cut that separates this region.

For this, we will need a structure that holds if any region has already been examined. A simple bitmap seems fine for this. Since you use at most 10 vertices, a 16 bit or 32 bit integer is appropriate. You can calculate the index of a region by setting the bits that refer to the contained vertices to 1. If you put all examined region indices in a hash set, you can find out if any region (or its complement) has been examined in O(1).

So start at any vertex (this will form the first region). Put its region index in the hash set. All edges incident to this vertex will form the first cut. Grow the region by any neighboring vertex. The region index can be calculated incrementally by ORing with the existing index. The second cut will be formed by all edges that start at any of the two vertices in the region and end somewhere else. Traverse the entire graph to find all possible regions (either in a BFS or DFS). Before you examine a region further, check if it or its complement has already been examined. Then you can break. If you do this for every vertex, you will find all possible cuts.

Before you report a cut, you need to check if the region's complement is still connected.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this procedure can get rid of a vertex from the region once it has added it.  E.g. suppose we start with vertex a, then add b, then c.  When will a cut be generated that contains just a and c, but not b, on one side?

Comment: If a and c are neighbors, this will happen sooner or later during DFS (when the recursive call to add b returns, you're again alone with a and can go on to c).

Comment: I see.  This will then ensure that a is always in the region (since when the recursive call for a returns the algorithm is finished) which has the nice side effect that you don't need to check whether the region's complement has been processed: regions always include a, complements of regions never do.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Haven't thought of this. But you still need to check the regions because equal regions may be formed by different paths (e.g. in the fully connected graph with a, b, c, d, the region a, b, c may be formed either by the path a, b, c or a, c, b).

Comment: Right, but actually I think you can get around this too!  Make the function take an extra parameter, namely a set of "forced out" vertices.  Initially this is empty.  After the recursive call that adds some vertex v to the current region returns and v is deleted from the current region, you add v to the "forced out" set: this prevents future *sibling* recursive calls from adding v and producing duplicates (e.g. it prevents a, c, b).  This is similar to how the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for enumerating all maximal cliques works.  Not 100% sure about correctness but I have to do other stuff now...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like any A and B can form a cut as long as they're disjoint, i.e. A does not have to be connected and similarly for B. In that case, since you say you have 10 or fewer vertices, if you want something really simple just take every choice of A of subset of vertices that is size 5 or smaller (by symmetry) and let B be the complement, and then for each edge test if it is an edge between A and B. All such edges form your cut. Store the set of edges for each cut. There will be at most 512 distinct cuts.

Now you say you want "minimal" cuts, i.e. cuts such that no proper subset of edges is a cut. Again, since you have only 512 maximum possible cuts, each a subset of edges of size no more than (10 choose 5)^2 edges, simply compare each pair of cuts C1,C2 such that the size of C1 is less than or equal to the size of C2. This will be easier if you either sort the edges in each cut for each pair of cuts, or use a fresh hash table to hash the edges in each cut for each pair of cuts.

Anyway, the point is that with only 512 cuts, each consisting of no more than (10 choose 5)^2 edges, you can do this computation in probably a matter of seconds or less (probably a fraction of a second) on a good modern a CPU, at least if you have a decent implementation in a lower level language like java or c/c++.

Comment: I think A and B each *do* have to be connected -- but that's not a big deal -- just do an O(|E|) connectivity test on each half of the 512 cuts.  Also the cuts that you suggest are already "minimal" by the OP's definition, since the only nonminimal cuts are those that contain an edge with both endpoints in the same side (but whose removal does not destroy the connectivity of that side).